# How to avoid kill command output message?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

script:

```
echo $$
fun()
{
    kill -9 $* && echo Signal Trapped
}

trap "fun" 10

while [ 1 ]
do  
    sleep 100 &
    trap "fun $!" 10
    wait $!
done
```

Output:

```
$ bash t.sh 
PID = 4243
Signal Trapped
t.sh: line 1:  4244 Killed                  sleep 100
Signal Trapped
```

when I execute the script, the above is output. Here, the message is shown as "t.sh: line 1:  4244 Killed                  sleep 100" once the process is killed. I tried the output and error redirection to /dev/null. But it does not worked. So, Is there any way to suppress the message which is arised by bash.

Comment: Do you run the script on another thread? ./script &

Comment: no. which means I want to run this script within another script. Is it right?

Comment: No you can run it like that in the terminal as well. It will start your script on another thread (since there is a loop in there, it might be god practice).

Comment: No. It does not work.

Comment: `[ 1 ]` is a really clunky way to write `true`.

Answer (score -1):

try with `dmesg -n -1`

the option `-n` permits to hide outputs with different levels